# wikipediaapi and "Special:Random"

Tags: python, wikipedia

I'm using wikipedia-api on Python (also known as wikipediaapi). This is the following code that I use:

```py
import wikipediaapi

wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')

page = wiki_wiki.page('Special:Random')

title = page.title
```

I'm expecting the output to be a random article name. How do I do this, or this repository didn't have anything for random articles?

Comment: Edited it to include the "import wikipediaapi" line in the original question so it should be right. The output that I got is just simply "Special:Random".

Comment: Is there anything in the docs of wikipedia api to suggest that should work? It's just a wrapper to the actual API, so why not use the API directly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614492/wikipedia-api-get-random-pages has all the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a random article title

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary")
title = json.loads(req.content)["title"]
```